# How can I make a list of all dataframes that are in my global environment?

Tags: r

I am trying to use `rbind` on them. But I need a list of all the `dataframes` that are already in my global environment. How can I do it?

Code I used to import the 20 csv files in  a directory. Basically, have to combine into a single dataframe.

```
temp = list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

Comment: Please provide the environment and context for your question.

Comment: R global environment. I have mentioned the context. I would like to rbind them.

Comment: Why is my question being downvoted?

Comment: It's really bad practice to have that many variables sitting around in the global environment. You should be putting all those data.frames directly into a list when you read them in.

Comment: Something like: `List = lapply(temp, read.csv)`

Comment: That is a mistake though. Because I am learning. Is that a reason to downvote?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your posted code, I would recommend you start a new R session, and read the files in again with the following code

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(pattern = ".csv"), read.csv))
```

Comment: This looks interesting..I am trying to do exactly this. By doing in one line. But I am getting this error: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: Then you'll have to do some checking.  Start with `lapply(list.files(pattern = ".csv"), read.csv)` and go through that list to see what the problem is (look at `dim` of each).  It's really hard to diagnose a problem that we can't see. Perhaps provide a small bit of data.

Answer (score 34):

This function should return a proper list with all the data.frames as elements

```
dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))
```

then you can rbind them with

```
do.call(rbind, dfs)
```

Of course it's awfully silly to have a bunch of data.frames lying around that are so related that you want to `rbind` them. It sounds like they probably should have been in a list in the first place.

I recommend you stay away from `assign()`; that's always a sign things are probably afoul. Try

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
dfs <- lapply(temp, read.csv)
```

that should return a list straight away.

Comment: Yeah, I think I am being silly. But I don't know the proper way to do it. Basically, I have 20 csv files, which I want to combine into one dataframe. Can you help with that from the start? I have attached the code I am using to import them

Comment: @maximusyoda I've updated with how to read into a list with `lapply`

Answer (score 7):

The `ls` function lists all things in your environment. The `get` function gets a variable with a given name. You can use the `class` function to get the class of a variable.

If you put them all together, you can do this:

```
ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) class(get(x))) == 'data.frame']
```

which will return a character vector of the data.frames in the current environment.

Comment: Does this work? I only get a list of filenames in a directory rather than the dataframes in the environment.

Comment: @maximusyoda No problem. ls lists environment stuff, dir lists the files. Don't forget to accept one of the answers.

Comment: No support for elements with multiple classes unfortunately, like tibbles. Great try though!

Comment: Hello MentatOfDune, thanks to you I discovered the **get()** function in R and solved a very interesting problem!

Answer (score 7):

If you only have data.frames with the same number of columns and column names in you global environment, the following should work (non-data.frame object don't matter):

```
do.call(rbind, eapply(.GlobalEnv,function(x) if(is.data.frame(x)) x))
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a slight improvement on MentatOfDune's answer, which does not catch data.frames with multiple classes:

```
ls()[grepl('data.frame', sapply(ls(), function(x) class(get(x))))]
```

Answer (score 5):

To improve MentatOfDune's answer (great username by the way):

```
ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) any(class(get(x)) == 'data.frame'))]
```

or even more robust:

```
ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)))]
```

This also supports tibbles (created with `dplyr` for example), because they contain multiple classes, where `data.frame` is one of them.

A readable version to get `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s using R 4 and higher:

```
ls() |> sapply(get) |> sapply(is.data.frame)
```

Finally super, super robust, also for package developers:

```
ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) is.data.frame(eval(parse(text = x), envir = globalenv())))]
```