# How to rbind a number of objects in r with same starting word but different number(in sequence) following it?

Tags: r

I have 121 data objects with names a1 a2 a3 ...so on till a121

How can I rbind it using a loop or something because writing the whole code

rbind(a1,a2,a3...) would be very tedious

Please help

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509879/how-can-i-make-a-list-of-all-dataframes-that-are-in-my-global-environment)?

Comment: Thanks Ronak. Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Reduce("rbind", mget(paste0("a", 1:121)))
```

Small example :

```
a1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
a2 <- c(2, 4, 1)
a3 <- c(1, 2, 3)

rbind(a1, a2, a3)

#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
#a1    1    2    3   
#a2    2    4    1
#a3    1    2    3

Reduce("rbind", mget(paste0("a", 1:3)))

# [,1] [,2] [,3]
#    1    2    3
#    2    4    1
#    1    2    3
```

Comment: Interesting, I did not know this could be done like this, I learnt something today.