# Extract name of data.frame in R as character

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I extract the name of a `data.frame` in R as a character?

For example, if I have `data.frame` named `df`, I want to get "df" as a character object.

Comment: What do you mean by extract? If you already know its name is `df` then use `'df'` and it will give you the character. From where?

Comment: have you looked at `ls()`?

Comment: I want to extract the name of the dataframe and save it as an object. For example, `name_of_dataframe` should be a character object that contains 'df'

Comment: @bouncyball I thought about that, but OP says ***a*** `data.frame` not all of them.

Comment: You may find something like what you want here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509879/how-can-i-make-a-list-of-all-dataframes-that-are-in-my-global-environment. Perhaps the answer by MentatOfDune.

Comment: Do you mean what is the original variable name of a data.frame parameter of a function?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
a <- data.frame()
deparse(substitute(a))
[1] "a"
```

This is also how `plot` knows what to put on the axes

Answer (score 7):

If you've got more than one dataframe that you want to retrieve the name of, you can use `ls.str(mode = "list")`. We use list because dataframes are stored as lists.

For example:

```
# make two dataframes
mydf1 <- data.frame(a = letters[1:10], b = runif(10))
mydf2 <- data.frame(a = letters[1:10], b = runif(10))

# see that dataframes are stored as lists:
storage.mode(mydf1)
[1] "list"

# store the names of the dataframes
names_of_dataframes <- ls.str(mode = "list")

# see the name of the first dataframe
names_of_dataframes[1]
[1] "mydf1"

# see the name of the second dataframe
names_of_dataframes[2]
[1] "mydf2"
```

Note that this method will also include the names of other list objects in your global environment. `ls.str` allows you to select the environment you want to search so you could store your dataframes in a different environment to other list objects.