# How to update the column-name without entering a string in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I am working with a [WHO macro](http://www.who.int/growthref/tools/en/) for transforming anthropometric parameters into Z-scores.

For the purpose of the question, calling the `who2007` function requires us to give the name of the data frame and then only the *name* of the variables (columns) just like in *ggplot* function. The problem with this is, say if the column name is `Age` entering `argument=Age` is different from entering `argument='Age'`. The former returns a `double` but the latter returns a `list`. I am assuming it is the difference of doing `df$Age` vs `df['Age']`.

If I have a vector of just the column names and I need to iterate over the same code using different columns each time, if I sequentially enter the respective entries of that character vector, the function throws an error since it encounters a list instead of a double internally. How do I circumvent this? One way I can think of is using the column-numbers or using any grep methods to identify the column numbers, but is there another better method?

ADDENDUM

Here is the function source code (a part of it which I think might explain the problem)

```
who2007 <- function(FileLab="Temp",FilePath="C:\\Documents and Settings",mydf,sex,age,weight,height,oedema=rep("n",dim(mydf)[1]),sw=rep(1,dim(mydf)[1])) {

#############################################################################
###########   Calculating the z-scores for all indicators
#############################################################################

   old <- options(warn=(-1))

   sex.x<-as.character(get(deparse(substitute(mydf)))[,deparse(substitute(sex))])
   age.x<-as.double(get(deparse(substitute(mydf)))[,deparse(substitute(age))])
   weight.x<-as.double(get(deparse(substitute(mydf)))[,deparse(substitute(weight))])
   height.x<-as.double(get(deparse(substitute(mydf)))[,deparse(substitute(height))])
   if(!missing(oedema)) oedema.vec<-as.character(get(deparse(substitute(mydf)))[,deparse(substitute(oedema))]) else oedema.vec<-oedema
   if(!missing(sw)) sw<-as.double(get(deparse(substitute(mydf)))[,deparse(substitute(sw))]) else sw<-as.double(sw)
   sw<-ifelse(is.na(sw),0,sw)

    sex.vec<-NULL
   sex.vec<-ifelse(sex.x!="NA" & (sex.x=="m" | sex.x=="M" | sex.x=="1"),1,ifelse(sex.x!="NA" & (sex.x=="f" | sex.x=="F" | sex.x=="2"),2,NA))
    age.vec<-age.x
    height.vec<-height.x
   oedema.vec<-ifelse(oedema.vec=="n" | oedema.vec=="N","n",ifelse(oedema.vec=="y" | oedema.vec=="Y","y","n"))

   mat<-cbind.data.frame(age.x,as.double(sex.vec),weight.x,height.x,oedema.vec,sw,stringsAsFactors=F)
    names(mat)<-c("age.mo","sex","weight","height","oedema","sw")

    mat$cbmi<-mat$weight/((height.vec/100)^2)
    mat$zhfa<-NULL
    mat$fhfa<-NULL
    mat$zwfa<-NULL
    mat$fwfa<-NULL
    mat$zbfa<-NULL
    mat$fbfa<-NULL

#############################################################################
###########   Calculating the z-scores for all indicators
#############################################################################

cat("Please wait while calculating z-scores...\n") 

### Height-for-age z-score

mat<-calc.zhfa(mat,hfawho2007)

### Weight-for-age z-score

mat<-calc.zwei(mat,wfawho2007)

### BMI-for-age z-score

mat<-calc.zbmi(mat,bfawho2007)


#### Rounding the z-scores to two decimals

            mat$zhfa<-rounde(mat$zhfa,digits=2)
            mat$zwfa<-rounde(mat$zwfa,digits=2)
            mat$zbfa<-rounde(mat$zbfa,digits=2)

#### Flagging z-score values for individual indicators

            mat$fhfa<-ifelse(abs(mat$zhfa) > 6,1,0)
            mat$fwfa<-ifelse(mat$zwfa > 5 | mat$zwfa < (-6),1,0)
            mat$fbfa<-ifelse(abs(mat$zbfa) > 5,1,0)

if(is.na(mat$age.mo) & mat$oedema=="y") {
mat$fhfa<-NA
mat$zwfa<-NA
mat$zbfa<-NA
}

mat<-cbind.data.frame(mydf,mat[,-c(2:6)])
```

ADDENDUM 2

The script is also intended to be run by ultiple users, where modifying the source code for them might not be possible. Is there a way to not need to modify the function source code?

Comment: if you're modifying every column, you could use mutate_all;

Comment: @RussHyde No, only a small subset of it.

Comment: Please provide example of your function `who2007`, it doesn't have to be complete function, simple enough so we can see input arguments, and data subsetting part. I am guessing you could pass colnames as character vector, and inside your function use `lapply` to loop through the columns?

Comment: @zx8754 I added the function. I did not get the second part of your comment.

Comment: I guess you can rewrite the function to accept strings to suit your need instead of using a series of `get` & `deparse(substitute())`

Comment: @Tung I do not know the usage of Deparse and the argument-handling as written in the function. Can you let me know what to change or what the current code does so that I can modify it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176431/extract-name-of-data-frame-in-r-as-character/45176503

Answer (score 1):

We could test if the input *dataframe* has required columns, then get rid of "deparse get" step, e.g.:

```
who2007 <- function(FileLab = "Temp", FilePath = "C:\\Documents and Settings",
                    mydf,
                    oedema = rep("n",dim(mydf)[1]),sw=rep(1,dim(mydf)[1])) {

  if(!all(c("sex", "age", "weight", "height") %in% colnames(mydf))) stop("mydf, must have 'sex', 'age', 'weight', 'height' columns")

  sex.x <- mydf$sex
  age.x <- mydf$age
  # ...
  # some code
  # ...

  #return
  list(sex.x, age.x)
}
```

Testing:

```
#example dataframe   
x <- head(mtcars)

# this errors as required columns are missing
who2007(mydf = x)
# Error in who2007(mydf = x) : 
#   mydf, must have 'sex', 'age', 'weight', 'height' columns

# now update columns with required column names, and it works fine:
colnames(x)[1:4] <- c("sex", "age", "weight", "height")
who2007(mydf = x)
# [[1]]
# [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6
```

Comment: Thanks. What exactly does `deparse get` do, seeing that its presence seems redundant?

Comment: @SatwikPasani Try: `deparse(substitute(sex))`

Comment: And there is no argument to put the name of the column (updated across iterations) in the function you mention. Am I missing something? Still a beginner at R

Comment: Also, can you check the addendum 2 in the question?

Comment: @SatwikPasani Not sure I understand, you want to fix the problem without doing any changes to the function?

Comment: If possible, yes. But now that I am reading up on substitute and deparse, it seems unlikely. And in the function you wrote, where to enter the iteratively updated column name?