# R get the table name of a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame which called `dat`, if there any function to get the name of this table (not the column names), the excepted output is "dat" which is a character.

Comment: u will get with **deparse** and **substitute** , ex: u have a data frame name "data1" : `deparse(substitue(data1))`. try the code and post in comments worked or not.

Comment: also check the below link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176431/extract-name-of-data-frame-in-r-as-character