# Paste Vectors without `rbind` function

Tags: r

I have 10 Vectors in my R environment. I want to paste this vectors for create a data frame. I used the `rbind` function, but i think that is very inefficient, because i have to type all variables in the function. The question is, can i use the `paste0` or `paste` function or other function like that, for paste this vectors?, thank you.

```
#Por ejemplo

x1 <- c(1, 2)
x2 <- c(3, 4)
x3 <- c(5, 6)
x4 <- c(7, 8)
x5 <- c(9, 10)
x6 <- c(11, 12)
x7 <- c(13, 14)
x8 <- c(15, 16)
x9 <- c(17, 18)
x10 <- c(19, 30)

rbind(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10)
```

I want to paste this vectors, without `rbind`, with some function like `paste0` or `paste`.

Comment: Why not use `rbind`? What do you mean `paste` which is reserved for character objects? Please show desired output.

Comment: The issue is that you create a bunch of sequentially named variables. Don't do that. Put them in a data structure, like a data frame or a list, from the very beginning.

Answer (score 5):

The `do.call` function is useful when the argument is a list and the function is expecting items that are just vectors. Since `mget`, which returns a list, is the natural tool when attempting to go from character to object names, you might try:

```
do.call(rbind, mget(paste0("x", 1:10)))
#---
    [,1] [,2]
x1     1    2
x2     3    4
x3     5    6
x4     7    8
x5     9   10
x6    11   12
x7    13   14
x8    15   16
x9    17   18
x10   19   30
```

Or using `matrix`

```
matrix(unlist(mget(paste0("x", 1:10))), ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: @Parfait Imo, it is fine. OP should know how to look up help files, but it wouldn't hurt to point to `?do.call` etc, I suppose. If anything is frowned on (by me), I guess it's the lack of admonition/critique to not make a bunch of vectors in the global environment like the OP has done (eg, throw in an "of course, it's silly" https://stackoverflow.com/a/25510018). Anyway, I guess further comments can go to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`ls()` returns a vector of all the variable names in your environment. If you do a regex for every variable name that begins with **x** then you can iterate over the new vector and `get()` them to call the variable with that name. If you call `get` in a `lapply` function, then you'll get a list of all the called variables. `do.call()` performs a function on every item in a list.

```
to_get <- ls()[grepl('^x', ls())]
to_bind <- lapply(to_get, get)
final_matrix <- do.call(rbind, to_bind)
```

Comment: or you could use `eapply`: `eapply(.GlobalEnv, identity)[grepl('^x', ls())]`

Comment: Thanks, very useful

Comment: I dont know how do that