# Create loop to check class and then ifelse check st_crs for items in data environment

Tags: r

I am probably overthinking this, but I have a bunch of data files, and I basically want to create a loop that checks the class, and then if it's a spatial dataframe, to run st_crs, so that I can look at the list of output and get an idea of the data.

Here is some dummy data to replicate my problem:

```
library(sf)
library(raster)

# ************************
# DUMMY DATA

# create dummy raster data
ncols <- 100   # Number of columns
nrows <- 100   # Number of rows
raster_data <- raster(matrix(runif(ncols * nrows), nrow = nrows, ncol = ncols))
extent(raster_data) <- extent(0, 1, 0, 1)
projection(raster_data) <- "+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84"

# load other dummy data
load(mtcars)
load(iris)
load(faithful)

# Create dummy sf data
sf_data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3),
  Name = c("Point A", "Point B", "Point C"),
  Latitude = c(40.7128, 34.0522, 51.5074),
  Longitude = c(-74.0060, -118.2437, -0.1278)
)

sf_object <- st_as_sf(data, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 4326)

# set a value I dont want in the loop
value_dummy <-  format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
```

Here is how I am imagining the loop will go:

```
# Loop
for(x in ls()){
  print(x)
  print(class(x))
  ifelse(class(x) == "sf" | class(x) == "raster", print(st_crs(x)), print(""))
}
```

As an added note, I really would prefer to just run through the dataframes and raster objects in the global environment, and not run through the values (e.g., things like ncols, nrows, value_dummy wouldn't be included in the loop). I have looked at answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509879/how-can-i-make-a-list-of-all-dataframes-that-are-in-my-global-environment), but that only seems to make a list of the dataframes and does not include the raster files.

Comment: You're abusing `ifelse`, it should not be used that way. Simply do `if (class(x) %in% c("sf", "raster")) print(st_crs(x)) else print("")`. (You can also use `if (inherits(x, c("sf", "raster"))) ...`, which is generally safer anyway since for some objects, `class(x)` will return a vector of length greater than 1; for instance, `class(tibble(mtcars))` or `class(Sys.time())`.)

Comment: You'll want `get`, see SOF?49167607, so you're testing an object rather than an `ls()` string, `objs2 = ls()`, `isSpatial_vec[i] = inherits(get(objs2[i]), c('sf','raster'))# (from a for)`; `sf::st_crs(get(objs2[isSpatial_vec]))[1]$input [1] "EPSG:4326"`, (from your data above) and as you'll likely want `crs` for rasters...a similar approach but running `inherits` twice as `raster::projection`, `terra::crs`.